# Fastest way to extract an unsigned short buffer to an unsigned char buffer?

Tags: c++, memory, buffer

I am wondering what is the fastest way to do the following problem using C++;

Here is the problem:
I have a 16-bit unsigned short image. There is some ROIs inside. I want to extract each ROI out to another buffer until the all ROI is done, but the output needs to be a unsigned char. Like the following diagram shows.

[image]

I have the the image height and width, the ROI height and width, and I have the pointer to the each ROI. I am wondering what is fastest way to do this job?  memset() and memcpy()? But the ROI is chopped, not continuously located in the buffer.

Anyone has any idea/experience/comments? Thanks a lot. (I am on Windwos 7 64-bit; VS2012)

Comment: Just cast to `unsigned char*`?!?